# Trouble drawing repeating and scrolling screen elements from a 2d array for an endless runner in swift

Tags: ios, spritekit

I've been trying draw level segments for an iOS endless runner using 2d elements that repeat forever. I have a class that generates a random 2d array, then scene elements are drawn and animated to move left based on the 2d array. I also have a random number of ground tiles that generate in between each segment. The problem is when I attempt to have this action repeated forever. Everything I've tried has failed. My question is, what is the most efficient way to achieve this without any spaces in between segments? My goal is to generate the new segment when the end gets close to the viewing area, whereas to not take up unnecissary memory. Here is my code that generates only one segment:

func generateSegment() {

```
let wholeBlock = SKTexture(imageNamed: "wholeblock")
let halfBlock = SKTexture(imageNamed: "halfblock")
let ySegment = self.frame.height / 9
let randomSpacer = Int(arc4random_uniform(12) + 5)
let startPoint = (ySegment * CGFloat(randomSpacer))
let tempBlock = SKSpriteNode(texture: wholeBlock)
let sizeDifference = ySegment / tempBlock.frame.height
var moveBlock = SKAction.moveByX(-tempBlock.frame.width, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.4))
var moveBlockForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveBlock)

// get random 2D Array
var segmentMatrix: [[Int]] = GetLevelSegment().atRandom() as! [[Int]]

//draw random number of ground spaces between segments
for var x = 0; x < randomSpacer; x++ {
    var groundSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: wholeBlock)
    groundSprite.setScale(sizeDifference)
    groundSprite.zPosition = 98
    groundSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    groundSprite.position = CGPointMake((CGFloat(x) * groundSprite.frame.size.width), 0)
    groundSprite.runAction(moveBlockForever)
    gameLayer.addChild(groundSprite)
}

//set segment start point

//draw a 32 x 9 segment
for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
    for var j = 0; j < 32; j++ {
        if segmentMatrix[i][j] == 1 {
            var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:wholeBlock)
            sprite.setScale(sizeDifference)
            sprite.zPosition = 98
            sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
            var xPosOne = CGFloat(j) * sprite.frame.size.height
            var xPosTwo = xPosOne + startPoint
            var segFromTop = CGFloat(i + 1) * sprite.frame.size.height
            var yPos = CGFloat(self.frame.height - segFromTop)
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(xPosTwo, yPos)
            sprite.runAction(moveBlockForever)
            gameLayer.addChild(sprite)
        }
        if segmentMatrix[i][j] == 2 {
            var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:halfBlock)
            sprite.setScale(sizeDifference)
            sprite.zPosition = 98
            sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
            var xPosOne = CGFloat(j) * sprite.frame.size.height
            var xPosTwo = xPosOne + startPoint
            var segFromTop = CGFloat(i + 1) * sprite.frame.size.height
            var yPos = CGFloat(self.frame.height - segFromTop)
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(xPosTwo, yPos)
            sprite.runAction(moveBlockForever)
            gameLayer.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a queue structure to represent the on-screen terrain; this approximates an infinite "ring-buffer".

Psuedo-code:

```
float maxCount = 20; //enough "terrainBlocks"(Sprites?) to fill the screen
//I only call this a "queue" because we add/remove from opposite ends
float Array<TerrainBlock> queue;
void fillQueue()
{
  while (queue.count < maxCount)
  {
     queue.apend(new TerrainBlock()); //Add "empty" blocks to the right
  }
}
void Init() //or ctor/loadContent/etc..
{
  fillQueue();
  foreach(TerrainBlock terrainBlock in queue)
    terrainBlock.LoadNewValues(); //Initialize the new blocks
}
void Update()
{
  foreach(TerrainBlock terrainBlock in queue)
    terrainBlock.Update(); //Update/animate the blocks
  while (queue[0].Location.X < 0) //If queue[0] is, now, off-screen...
  {
    TerrainBlock deadBlock = queue[0]; //get the one we're killing
    queue.removeAtIndex(0); //remove it from the left
    deadBlock.LoadNewValues(); //Reset the values for this "new" TerrainBlock, from disk
    queue.append(deadBlock); //add it right back to the right
  } //continue until queue[0] is the left-most on-screen block...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm currently trying this method.  I have a question about list/vectors if you don't mind.  It seems I'd be able to access each item in the list at will, which better suits my needs.  Is there a tutorial on how to create this data structure in swift, or is there one available online I can just download?  I cant seem to find anything about it.

Comment: @tedesignz, I'm willing to help you find more information, but I have none of my own regarding iOS. I was able to find [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html). It seems to indicate an array will work just fine as a "queue". Check out the bold heading "Accessing and Modifying an Array" for usage of `append()` and `removeAtIndex()`; they correspond to my `add()` and `pop()`, respectively.

Comment: @tedesignz, I've revised the code to be more "swift" (I think) and optimized a little.

Comment: I've got it working using a method similar to what you suggested.  I'm using a 2d array sort of as a queue.  once the left col is off screen, all values are shifted to the left and a new col is fed in from a pre-designed matrix of integers.  Once the feeder is empty, it generates a new one at random.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! you've been a big help.